# Slider not displaying images (BX Slider)

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, slider, bxslider

Maybe you could help me with a problem I am currently solving for few hours.

I have a WordPress website that uses bxSlider plugin. On the development version http://topdodavatel.cz/ipcorder/ everything worked fine, but now the images won't appear unless I examine the element (then they appear).

I checked all the source .js files, but they seem fine.

Comment: Your problem is `.bx-viewport` has `height:0px;` and `overflow:hidden;`. On window resize it seems to alter itself. I've not found the root cause as of yet but I'll keep looking.

Comment: Thank you for your help @asherstoppard, now it is working - the theme code contained ul.bxslider {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 display: none;
}

Comment: I do not know how it could work before with display:none; in the theme, but now it works fine I think. Thank you very much for your assistance.

Comment: No problem, disregard my last answer =)

Comment: Thank you very much @AndreMorgan - problem is solved now :)

Answer (score 0):

Theme contained

```
 ul.bxslider { margin: 0; padding: 0; display: none; }
```

which prevented the images from being displayed.